# HTML Email Formatting not rendering correctly in MS Outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook, width

I have used the Ink boilerplate HTML and CSS files to create an HTML email blast. I have added the CSS to the head of the email, and used Zurb's Inliner to inline the styles.

The email is rendering correctly on multiple clients - but not MS Outlook 2010. Outlook is not honoring the max-width tag (which I understand is not supported) but I have also added width tags in an effort to maintain correct formatting in Outlook.

Is anyone able to identify what I might be missing here?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO8Cs.jpg)

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

```
![<!-- Inliner Build Version 4380b7741bb759d6cb997545f3add21ad48f010b -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <!-- For testing only -->
    </head>
    <body style="width: 100% !important; min-width: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; text-align: left; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <style type="text/css">
        </style>
        <table class="body" style="max-width: 584px; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; height: 100%; width: 584px;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">
            <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                <td class="center" align="center" valign="top" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: center;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                    <center style="width: 100%; max-width: 584px;">
                        <!-- Email Content -->
                        <table class="container" width="584px" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: inherit; width: 584px; display: block !important; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">
                            <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                                <td style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="left" valign="top">
                                    <!-- first section begin -->
                                    <table class="row" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 100%; position: relative; display: block; padding: 0px;">
                                        <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                                            <!-- first item begin -->
                                            <td class="wrapper" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; position: relative;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 10px 20px 0px 0px;" align="left" valign="top">
                                                <table class="two columns" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 80px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">
                                                    <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                                                        <td class="center panel" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: center;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px;  margin: 0; padding: 10px; " align="center" bgcolor="ffffff" valign="top">
                                                            <center style="width: 100%; min-width: 60px;">
                                                                <!-- Centered image --> 
                                                                <img class="center" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/smaaoink/logo1.gif" alt="" width="97px" style="display: block; max-width: 100%; width: 100%; height: auto !important; outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; float: none; clear: both; margin: 0 auto;" align="none" />
                                                            </center>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="expander" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0px;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="left" valign="top"></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                            <!-- first item end -->
                                            <!-- second item begin -->
                                            <td class="wrapper last" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; position: relative;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 10px 0px 0px;" align="left" valign="top">
                                                <table class="eight columns" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 380px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">
                                                    <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                                                        <td class="center panel" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: center;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px;  margin: 0; padding: 10px; " align="center" bgcolor="ffffff" valign="top">
                                                            <center style="width: 100%; min-width: 360px;">
                                                                <!-- Centered image --> 
                                                                <img class="center" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/smaaoink/logo2.gif" alt="Alabama Outdoors" width="487px" style="display: block; max-width: 100%; width: 100%; height: auto !important; outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; float: none; clear: both; margin: 0 auto;" align="none" />
                                                            </center>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="expander" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0px;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="left" valign="top"></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <!-- first section end --><!-- second section begin -->
                            <table class="row" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 100%; position: relative; display: block; padding: 0px;">
                                <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                                    <!-- first item begin -->
                                    <td class="wrapper" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; position: relative;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 10px 20px 0px 0px;" align="left" valign="top">
                                        <table class="four columns" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 180px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">
                                            <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                                                <td class="center panel" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: center;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px;  margin: 0; padding: 10px; " align="center" bgcolor="ffffff" valign="top">
                                                    <center style="width: 100%; min-width: 160px;">
                                                        <!-- Centered image --> 
                                                        <img class="center" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/smaaoink/dealsv5.gif" alt="Exclusive Deals" width="292" style="display: block; max-width: 100%; width: 100%; height: auto !important; outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; float: none; clear: both; margin: 0 auto;" align="none" />
                                                    </center>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="expander" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0px;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="left" valign="top"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <!-- first item end -->
                                    <!-- second item begin -->
                                    <td class="wrapper last" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; position: relative;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 10px 0px 0px;" align="left" valign="top">
                                        <table class="eight columns" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 380px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">
                                            <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                                                <td class="center panel" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: center;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px;  margin: 0; padding: 10px; " align="center" bgcolor="ffffff" valign="top">
                                                    <center style="width: 100%; min-width: 360px;">
                                                        <!-- Centered image --> 
                                                        <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/smaaoink/20v5.gif" alt="Save on Patagonia, TNF and more" width="292" style="display: block; max-width: 100%; width: 100%; height: auto !important; outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; float: left; clear: both;" align="left" />
                                                    </center>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="expander" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0px;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="left" valign="top"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!-- second item end--><!-- second section end --><!-- third section begin --><!-- first item begin -->
                            <table class="row" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 100%; position: relative; display: block; padding: 0px;">
                                <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                                    <td class="wrapper last" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; position: relative;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 10px 0px 0px;" align="left" valign="top">
                                        <table class="twelve columns" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 580px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">
                                            <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                                                <td class="center panel" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: center;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px;  margin: 0; padding: 10px; " align="center" bgcolor="ffffff" valign="top">
                                                    <center style="width: 100%; min-width: 560px;">
                                                        <!-- Centered image --> 
                                                        <img class="center" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/smaaoink/storewide1200.gif" alt="" width="584" style="display: block; max-width: 100%; width: 100%; height: auto !important; outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; float: none; clear: both; margin: 0 auto;" align="none" />
                                                    </center>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="expander" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0px;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="left" valign="top"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <!-- first item end -->
                                    <!-- third section end -->
                                    <!-- fourth section begin -->
                                    <!-- first item begin -->
                                    <table class="row" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 100%; position: relative; display: block; padding: 0px;">
                                        <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                                            <td class="wrapper" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; position: relative;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 10px 20px 0px 0px;" align="left" valign="top">
                                                <table class="six columns" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 280px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">
                                                    <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                                                        <td class="center panel" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: center;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px;  margin: 0; padding: 10px; " align="center" bgcolor="ffffff" valign="top">
                                                            <center style="width: 100%; min-width: 260px;">
                                                                <!-- Centered image --> 
                                                                <img class="center" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/smaaoink/p1new.gif" alt="Exclusive Deals" width="292" style="display: block; max-width: 100%; width: 100%; height: auto !important; outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; float: none; clear: both; margin: 0 auto;" align="none" />
                                                            </center>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="expander" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0px;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="left" valign="top"></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="wrapper last" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; position: relative;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 10px 0px 0px;" align="left" valign="top">
                                                <table class="six columns" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 280px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">
                                                    <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                                                        <td class="center panel" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: center;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px;  margin: 0; padding: 10px; " align="center" bgcolor="ffffff" valign="top">
                                                            <center style="width: 100%; min-width: 260px;">
                                                                <!-- Centered image --> 
                                                                <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/smaaoink/p2new.gif" alt="Save on Patagonia, TNF and more" width="292" style="display: block; max-width: 100%; width: 100%; height: auto !important; outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; float: left; clear: both;" align="left" />
                                                            </center>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="expander" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0px;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="left" valign="top"></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <table class="row" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 100%; position: relative; display: block; padding: 0px;">
                                        <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                                            <td class="wrapper" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; position: relative;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 10px 20px 0px 0px;" align="left" valign="top">
                                                <table class="six columns" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 280px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">
                                                    <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                                                        <td class="center panel" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: center;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px;  margin: 0; padding: 10px; " align="center" bgcolor="ffffff" valign="top">
                                                            <center style="width: 100%; min-width: 260px;">
                                                                <!-- Centered image --> 
                                                                <img class="center" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/smaaoink/p3new.gif" alt="Exclusive Deals" width="292" style="display: block; max-width: 100%; width: 100%; height: auto !important; outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; float: none; clear: both; margin: 0 auto;" align="none" />
                                                            </center>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="expander" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0px;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="left" valign="top"></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="wrapper last" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; position: relative;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 10px 0px 0px;" align="left" valign="top">
                                                <table class="six columns" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 280px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">
                                                    <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                                                        <td class="center panel" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: center;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px;  margin: 0; padding: 10px; " align="center" bgcolor="ffffff" valign="top">
                                                            <center style="width: 100%; min-width: 260px;">
                                                                <!-- Centered image --> 
                                                                <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/smaaoink/p4new.gif" alt="Save on Patagonia, TNF and more" width="292" style="display: block; max-width: 100%; width: 100%; height: auto !important; outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; float: left; clear: both;" align="left" />
                                                            </center>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="expander" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0px;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="left" valign="top"></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <table class="row" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 100%; position: relative; display: block; padding: 0px;">
                                        <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                                            <td class="wrapper" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; position: relative;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 10px 20px 0px 0px;" align="left" valign="top">
                                                <table class="six columns" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 280px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">
                                                    <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                                                        <td class="center panel" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: center;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px;  margin: 0; padding: 10px; " align="center" bgcolor="ffffff" valign="top">
                                                            <center style="width: 100%; min-width: 260px;">
                                                                <!-- Centered image --> 
                                                                <img class="center" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/smaaoink/p5new.gif" alt="Exclusive Deals" width="292" style="display: block; max-width: 100%; width: 100%; height: auto !important; outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; float: none; clear: both; margin: 0 auto;" align="none" />
                                                            </center>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="expander" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0px;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="left" valign="top"></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="wrapper last" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; position: relative;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 10px 0px 0px;" align="left" valign="top">
                                                <table class="six columns" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 280px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">
                                                    <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                                                        <td class="center panel" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: center;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px;  margin: 0; padding: 10px; " align="center" bgcolor="ffffff" valign="top">
                                                            <center style="width: 100%; min-width: 260px;">
                                                                <!-- Centered image --> 
                                                                <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/smaaoink/p6new.gif" alt="Save on Patagonia, TNF and more" width="292" style="display: block; max-width: 100%; width: 100%; height: auto !important; outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; float: left; clear: both;" align="left" />
                                                            </center>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="expander" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; visibility: hidden; width: 0px;  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="left" valign="top"></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <!-- PATA PRODUCT END --><!-- END Email Content -->
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </table>
                    </center>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the "**px**" in all width **attributes** (not in styles!), like width="584**px**" -> width="584". And you're good to go...

Comment: than you SO much I never would have figured that out. Worked a charm!